# Htaccess Rewrite Rule with a PERIOD

Tags: .htaccess

I need a rule that when someone types

domain.com/finddomain.com it points to domain.com?q=finddomain.com

Very simple, yet the period in "finddomain.com" is causing my rule to fail.

My rule is:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9.]+)(/)?$ index.php?q=$1
```

The "." screw it up.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Tried escaping it with a backslash (\\)? Periods are valid regex metacharacters.

Answer (score 13):

You have to escape the period with a backslash `\.` because the period stands for *any* character.

So your RegEx `^([A-Za-z0-9.]+)(/)?$` does actually match every string.. It should be `^([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)/?$` (or `^([A-Za-z0-9\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]+)/?$` to match only domains with a TLD).

Answer (score 3):

try to escape the dot, since dot in regular expressions denote "anything"

cheers